# Is there any way to perform endmember estimation (N-Finder)?

Tags: r, spectra, hyperspec

In PLS/PCR we can get a RMSE-components curve [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Rqc.png) to decide the number of components. Similarly, can we obtain such a curve for N-finder analysis to decide the number of endmembers for the data?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8eHe.png)

I could get the endmembers for my data. But there is always ambiguity in deciding the end members.
What could be the best way to decide the number of endmembers is not known to me.

Comment: Hi Tanny, welcome to SO. This site is specifically for debugging code and programming issues. Your question is considered off-topic for SO, but [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a great place to ask these types of questions. Also, you have posted the same image twice. Thanks